# Use of Logger with Ruby and RSpec

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec

I have created logger object in "spec/logger.rb" and returned it.
I have created logger object in "spec/test1.rb" in describe method and can use it. it is working in same directory. If i need to use logger by creating logger object or by including file in different directory with and without class, then is there any way to do it ?

`spec/logger.rb`

```
class Logging
    def initialize_logger()    
        log = Logger.new("test.log")
        return log
    end
end
```

`spec/test1.rb`

```
require 'java'
require 'rspec'
require 'logger'

require "logger.rb"

class SingleTest
  describe 'Verify Single Test' do
    # create logger object
    logger_object = Logging.new
    logger = logger_object.initialize_logger()
    logger.info 'Checking Logger'

    it 'Verify Single Test for logger is present' do
      logger.info 'Creating logger'
    end
  end
end
```

`lib/test_lib1.rb`

```
require 'httparty'
require '../utility/logger.rb'

@logger_object = Logging.new
@logger = @logger_object.initialize_logger()

@logger.info 'Checking Logger'

def first()
  @logger.info "first logger in lib"
end

def perform_url_request()
  @logger.info "URL"
  @logger.info "Request Method"
end
```

`lib/test_lib2.rb`

```
require '../utility/logger.rb'

class TestFile
  def initialize()
    @logger_object = Logging.new
    @logger = @logger_object.initialize_logger()
    @logger.info "I am intialize"
  end

  def test_method()
    @logger.info "******"
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?  This seem convoluted. What is the expectation of your test?

Comment: what is the error message? what is not working? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to use logger in all the files, but ruby doesn't allow multiple inheritance.